# Elementary Sobolev space problem

Tags: sobolev-spaces

For which $k$ does the following function belong to Sobolev space $H^k(-1,1)$:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases} x e^{-  \frac{1}{x} } & x > 0\\0 & x  \leq  0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Strictly speaking, none, because if it is to be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ then it isn't even square integrable. Presumably you intend a domain with an upper bound. Anyway, to help you think about it, notice that the only candidate for a "bad point" is zero. Elsewhere all the derivatives are just given by (integration against) smooth functions.

Comment: I apologize, Hk(-1, 1) is space in question, I'll try to correct if it's possible. Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: A function $\,f\,$ is in Sobolev space $\, H^k\,$ if and only if the $\,k$-th derivative $\,f^{(k)}\,$ is in $\,L^2\,$:

$$
f\in H^k\big(\Omega \big) \iff f^{(k)} = \frac{d^kf}{dx^k}\in L^2\big(\Omega \big)
$$

---

Let us compute a few derivatives of your function:

\begin{align}
f\left(x\right) &=
\begin{cases} 
x \,e^{ - \frac{1}{x} } &&&&& x \in \left(0, 1\right) \\
0, &&&&& x \in \left(-1, 0\right]
\end{cases}
\\
f'\left(x\right) &=
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{1+x}{x}\,e^{ -\frac{1}{x} }, &&& x \in \left(0, 1\right) \\
0 , &&& x \in \left(-1, 0\right]
\end{cases}
\\
f''\left(x\right) &=
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{1}{x^3}\,e^{ -\frac{1}{x^3} }, &&&& x \in \left(0, 1\right) \\
0 , &&&& x \in \left(-1, 0\right]
\end{cases}
\\
f'''\left(x\right) &=
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{1-3 x}{x^5}\,e^{-\frac{1}{x}} , &&& x \in \left(0, 1\right) \\
0 , &&& x \in \left(-1, 0\right]
\end{cases}
\\
f''''\left(x\right) &=
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{12 x^2 - 8 x + 1}{x^7}\,e^{-\frac{1}{x}} , & x \in \left(0, 1\right) \\
0 , & x \in \left(-1, 0\right]
\end{cases}
\end{align}

---

What happens to the order of multiplier of exponent $\displaystyle\,e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\,$ in $\;f^{\left(k\right)}\,$ as $\, k\to \infty$?
What can we conclude about integrability of $\;f^{\left(k\right)}$? 
Hope you can pick it from here.

---

**PS** As a reminder, because of the [Poincaré inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality) we only need to worry about integrability of a highest derivative of $\,f,\,$ because it provides a bound for norms of all derivatives of lower order.

Comment: I realy like your hint, I suppose it work only for $k >0$ do you have one for $k<0$ , I mean the dual space